# Play multiple html5 video on single page (not simultaneously) using backbone.js and jw player

Tags: ios, html, backbone.js, jwplayer, html5-video

I am using backbone.js to replace content on a page. After backbone places the new content I call a JW Player script to create a video (Flash normal web, HTML5 video tag on iOS).

When I play one video, stop that video, use backbone to replace the video, click to play the new video... the new video just has a spinner and won't play. (this only happens in iOS devices)

Has anyone had this issue that knows what might be happening and how to fix it?

This content is getting updated via backbone.

```
<div class="media-wrapper">
    <div class="media-holder"><div id="media"></div></div>
</div>
```

This function is being called after backbone and creates the video on the div above.

```
function create_video(url,w,h,thumb)
{
    jwplayer('media').setup({
        flashplayer: '/api/js/jwp/player.swf',
        skin: '/api/js/jwp/video.zip',
        wmode: 'opaque',
        image: thumb,
        file: url,
        height: h,
        width: w
    });
}
```

I am pretty sure it is not JW Player, but something to do with iOS and how it handles html5 videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug[1] with using the same div and calling setup multiple times.  The forum post linked to from the bug has the simple workaround of incrementing your div id each time you call setup.

[1] http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/ticket/1615

Comment: Thanks man, making the divs have dynamic IDs fixed the issue.